# Dynamic CSS changeable from website`s CMS

Tags: css, templates, database-design, content-management-system

The situation:

I have a website with a single template (css,images,HTML,js).
Also have and a CMS connected to the website.
My customer wants to dynamically change everything from the website's style-design.
I`m wondering how to implement that in my code..
Is there some unique/best practice for that?!

My options through my eyes:

1. Store every setting into the database and collect the data every time the website load(more like stupid idea)
2. When he changes the settings, I'll just take the original css and replace the needed things.

Then I'll use the new css file for loading the website.

I`m sure that there is a way better option..

Can you help me with the idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the option to upload files in your CMS?

Why not allow the user to upload the CSS file, with a certain name, in a certain directory (make sure you have a proper fallback default). My assumption here is that one extra query won't break your site (especially since the CSS will be cached).

Comment: The thing is that the client don`t even know what is CSS...
He must be able with some interface to control the things he like.

Comment: Then it really depends on the specific solution you are using, perhaps discuss it with the CMS vendor? They will have experience with this.